# Convert UTF-8 To UTF-7 in Python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, utf-7

I am trying to find a way to implement this in python:
[CyberChef Example](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=Encode_text(%27UTF-7%20(65000)%27)&input=PHJvb3Q%2BPHRlc3Q%2BYWFhPC90ZXN0PjxoZWw%2BYXNkPC9oZWw%2BPC9yb290Pg)

I want to convert from UTF-8 to UTF-7.

For example, given the string

```
<root><test>aaa</test><hel>asd</hel></root>
```

The encoded output should be the bytes

```
+ADw-root+AD4-+ADw-test+AD4-aaa+ADw-/test+AD4-+ADw-hel+AD4-asd+ADw-/hel+AD4-+ADw-/root+AD4-
```

I tried using codec and decode('utf-7') but this just returns the string as is:

```
>>> "<root><test>aaa</test><hel>asd</hel></root>".encode("utf-7")
b'<root><test>aaa</test><hel>asd</hel></root>'
```

Comment: No one should be using this stupid obsolete UTF-7 thing, and no one should be using these stupid programming puzzle websites, so ignoring this particular task is a double win. Having said that, there are multiple ways to encode characters as UTF-7. What Python does and what that side shows are both correct ways to encode that string.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI in my case I have to use UTF-7 as I am building a web vulnerability scanner that detects XXE vulnerabilities and using UTF-7 encoding is a common thing to bypass WAFs.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI also Cyberchef comes in very handy at this particular point and many others and is used by many people who do cyber security challenges in capture the flag competitions. It's not fair to call it stupid, many people appreciate it.

Comment: @user7864052 The actual encoding is happening here: https://github.com/SheetJS/js-codepage/blob/d5f23335d5335ee7d241b6c9e7f2ea124a07f616/dist/cputils.js#L385C5-L385C17   There's also decoding function in that file.

Answer (score 2):

`<` and `>` are among what [UTF-7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-7) ([RFC 2152](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2152)) calls "optional direct characters". These characters allowed to be either directly encoded as their ASCII equivalents, or be encoded using a Unicode shifted encoding. Python's UTF-7 implementation chooses to use direct encodings for all optional direct characters.

For example, when encoding to UTF-7, Python maps `<` to its single-byte ASCII representation `b'<'`:

```
>>> "<".encode("utf-7")
b'<'
```

When decoding bytes from UTF-7, Python will happily handle either a direct encoding or Unicode shifted encoding for `<`:

```
>>> b"+ADw-".decode("utf-7")
'<'
>>> b"<".decode("utf-7")
'<'
```

If you want to obtain a Unicode shift encoding for `<` (or for other optional direct characters), you'll need to either a) manually convert the direct-encoded characters to their Unicode shift equivalents, or b) use a different UTF-7 implementation that provides more fine-grained encoding controls.

To manually convert `<` and `>` from direct encodings to Unicode shift encodings, you can use [`bytes.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.replace):

```
text = "<root><test>aaa</test><hel>asd</hel></root>"
payload = text.encode("utf-7")
payload = payload.replace(b"<", b"+ADw-")
payload = payload.replace(b">", b"+AD4-")

>>> print(payload)
b'+ADw-root+AD4-+ADw-test+AD4-aaa+ADw-/test+AD4-+ADw-hel+AD4-asd+ADw-/hel+AD4-+ADw-/root+AD4-'

>>> text == payload.decode("utf-7")
True
```

Comment: Converting characters manually seems like a hustle, it would be nicer to have something that's already implemented. Thanks for the answer, really appreciated.